# Weird input data, no newline character in the whole buffer 4194304, not supported a.t.m

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a neo4j graph, trying to import some data, but some import error happens, here is the log:

```
Import error: Weird input data, no newline character in the whole buffer 4194304, not supported a.t.m.
Caused by:Weird input data, no newline character in the whole buffer 4194304, not supported a.t.m.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Weird input data, no newline character in the whole buffer 4194304, not supported a.t.m.
        at org.neo4j.csv.reader.ClosestNewLineChunker.nextChunk(ClosestNewLineChunker.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.LazyCsvInputChunk.fillFrom(LazyCsvInputChunk.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInputChunkProxy.fillFrom(CsvInputChunkProxy.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInputIterator.next(CsvInputIterator.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInput.sample(CsvInput.java:238)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.CsvInput.calculateEstimates(CsvInput.java:199)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ImportLogic.initialize(ImportLogic.java:202)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:88)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.doImport(ImportTool.java:585)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:128)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.ImportCommand.execute(ImportCommand.java:236)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:127)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:51)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: VM pause monitor is not started
                at org.neo4j.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:142)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.monitoring.VmPauseMonitor.stop(VmPauseMonitor.java:71)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.OnDemandDetailsExecutionMonitor.done(OnDemandDetailsExecutionMonitor.java:128)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.done(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:82)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.done(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:82)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ImportLogic.close(ImportLogic.java:520)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:99)
                ... 5 more

WARNING Import failed. The store files in /data/databases/npm_0607.db are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually
unexpected error: Weird input data, no newline character in the whole buffer 4194304, not supported a.t.m.
```

I am working on a docker container of neo4j
When I tried with a smaller scale of data, everything works fine, but when I tried with 6 times data size, this error happens, and the size of csv files are almost 14GB totally
At first, I thought it is because of the files' size, but I tried seperating it into smaller files, but still the same error.

I am using `bin/neo4j-admin import` for the import

Anyone konws what is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j's batch import logic tries to break up large input data into smaller chunks so that multiple parsers can process them simultaneously. The logic looks for newlines to determine where to separate the chunks. If your data has very infrequent or no newlines, then chunking fails with the error you are seeing.

You may need to reformat your input data so that it contains more frequent newlines.

Comment: I was trying to import data which have longest csv line as 15MB, I tried to modify the config source code of neo4j and recompile it, but it seems doesn't work... Then I saved all my data in mongodb and keep the id  as property in graph to make the newlines more frequent, it works and the speed on querying is still reasonable, thanks for you explaination!